Why is the transaction fee very high?
I am sending transaction to Sepolia testnet from browser. The code I have is:
await provider.request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [
          {
            from: account.address,
            to: address,
            gas: `${gas}`,
            maxFeePerGas: `${gasPrice}`,
            value: `${cellPriceInWei}`,
            data: await contract.methods
              .testTransfer()
              .encodeABI(),
          },
        ],
      });

the fee values for above request is:
gas: 457208
maxFeePerGas: 1000639263 
value: 1000000000000000 

based on above values, the maximum fee for this transaction should be
gas * maxFeePerGas = 457208 * 1000639263 = 457500276157704 wei = 0.00045 ether
the value in the transaction is 1000000000000000 = 0.001 ether.
so the total amount should be 0.001 + 0.00045 = 0.00145 ether. But when the metamask is open, it shows 0.006 estimated fee and the total is 1.159 ether. (shown in below screen shot)
I understand that there could be some adjustment on the transaction fee but I don't expect it is too much different. Why is the actual fee so high?
The contact can be found at: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x47cf1fB2e5579D746F1Bcfce33aDd887d19fbAA3
The source code for testTransfer is:
function testTransfer() public payable {
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    }

The ABI for above method testTransfer is:
{
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "testTransfer",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "function"
    }



Can you share the contract address and ABI of the test() function with which you're interacting ?

The contract can be found: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x47cf1fB2e5579D746F1Bcfce33aDd887d19fbAA3.

I have put the ABI in the question

Can you also share the minimum reproducible version of your corresponding function ?

I have wrote a new function which only has one statement in the post. It is a very simple function. Can you see if you can find anything wrong with it?

When I'm calling testTransfer(), it's not showing that much transaction fee. In your case, it's showing 1.159 ETH, when you're passing value as 1000000000000000 wei (0.001 ether) even in case of the testTransfer() function ?

How do you call this function? do you have any tool to call it easily? What is the transaction fee and total amount you get?

I was calling it using Remix IDE.

oh I can verify it as well. Yes you are right, calling testTransfer only cost 0.0003 gas fee. I just figured out which cost most which is a map.push. I have a field mapping(address => Sector[]) private users, and call users.push(msg.sender()) cost 0.001 ether even for an empty map. Is it expected to have that high gas cost just pushing an address in a map?

Yeah, most probably, because read/write operations on storage variables are costly, and even more costly when it comes to arrays and mappings.

0.001 ether is about $4 which is the only gas part of the transaction. Who would use mapping if the cost is that high?

Do you have to put the code in remix to compile and deploy first in order to call it? how do you call an existing contract without compiling in Remix?

Without compiling, we can’t interact with the contract in Remix. In order to interact with the existing contract, you need to compile the contract code or its Interface in Remix, then use the Load Contract from Address button, by passing the address in the text-field.

if I use Load contract from Address, what the point to compile the code?

Because, without compilation, it won’t be having ABI to match.

can I paste the ABI into remix to use?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
